# Git diff branch against working tree not including merges

Tags: git, merge

I am trying to find the diff between the current working tree and another branch (e.g. master) not including the merge commits.

```
. --a--> . --b--> . (master)
 \       \
  c       \ (merge)
   \       \
    . ----- . --d--> . (current) --e--> (working tree)
```

Now, `git diff master` does show the working tree changes, however it also shows changes in master not in current (-b, c, d, e). I want to see these changes not in master, that is, I want to see c, d and e.

I've tried using the [triple-dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462974/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-git-commit-ranges) notation or using [git log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549157/show-non-merge-differences-for-two-commits-in-git), but these compare against the tip (last commit):

```
git diff master...
git diff master...current_branch

git log -p --no-merges current..master
```

returns c and d, i.e. they don't include e: the working tree.

How can I get this diff to include the working tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point to remember here is that if **both branches share commit X** then **this adds nothing to the diff**, that is, you don't see anything about commit X in the diff*.

Therefore you only need to diff against the branching point (which you can find with [merge-base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527234/finding-a-branch-point-with-git)) and diff against that:

```
git diff $(git merge-base current master)
```

returns c, d and e.

This also works if the story is for those which are seemingly more complex (with several merges):

```
. --a--> . --b--> . --- . (master)
 \       \             /
  c       \ (merge)   / (merge)
   \       \         /
    . ----- . ----- . --d--> . (current) --e--> (working tree)
```

returns d and e.

* This explains why you don't see `a` in `git diff master`.

I bet you feel silly for asking now!